# Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\Users\user\'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I've just installed nodejs then just to confirm its availability running node -v shows the version of node installed but on running npm -v it  displays

```
Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\Users\user\'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm'
```

tried to find the .npmrc to change the

```
prefix="D:\\node\\node_global"
```

I also can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

open .npmrc file from the 'C:\Users\user'-> edit prefix path to `prefix='C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm'`.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file .npmrc in your User folder, and focus on the setting `prefix={path}`. Delete the " or ' in  the path . Have a try.